# seperate text to columns in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

How can you separate text into columns from right to left? My data has an inconsistent number of spaces per row, e.g.:

```
Hernandez Landscaping Gus Hernandez 1 Neurys Lane Newark, DE 19702
Hershey's Mill Golf Club Steve Friedell 1000 Mill Road West Chester, PA 19380
Hershey Country Club 1000 E.Derry Rd Hershey, PA 17033
Hershey Gardens 170 Hotel Road Hershey PA 17033
```

Comment: It looks like your first 2 columns (I'm guessing company name & contact name) can both have a variable number of words.  Are you using any delimiters other than space / are there quotes around your data?  If not there's no way to tell whether `A B C` is `'A B', 'C'` or `'A', 'B C'`

Comment: no other delimiters used.  I was hoping there was a way to say "split it by spaces starting from right to left.  That wouldn't fix it all, but get me close.

Comment: How many records do you have?  Even starting from the right will not be easy to automate because of varying numbers of words in city names and street addresses, lots of variations and exceptions in addressing, etc.  Unless you have a tremendous list, it will probably be faster to do it manually because it is an easy task for a person to recognize the address components in all of their variations.  Start from the right and cut away one field at a time and paste it.

Comment: it's a long list...1027 lines..ugh

Comment: You haven't said what the data is that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...  In this example I assume you paste your data into cell A2, so you have row 1 for headers.  When you split by columns the data fills columns A to M; with N being the first blank column; adjust column references as appropriate for your data.

- Use Data, Text to Columns to split by delimiter, selecting space (normal left to right)
- In the column after your last one (i.e. N) put `=countblanks(A2:M2)` in row 2; then copy this formula for all rows (excel will auto increment the row number as required).
- In O1 type `2`
- In P1 put the formula `=O2+2`
- in O2 type `=IF($N2+O$1>COLUMN(N2),"",INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("C[-",$N2+O$1,"]"),FALSE))`
- Copy N2 and O2 for all columns (row numbers should update automatically)
- Copy column O to the right, so you have the same formula repeated (with updated references) to column AA (or beyond if your data requires).
- You should now see that columns O through AA have your data as if it had been reverse split
- Select columns O to AA, right click, and select Copy (or press ctrl+c)
- On a new sheet click cell A2, right click, and select Paste Values (also found under Paste Special).  You now have a sheet with only the results you want, and without the formulas you'd used to create it.

**Results**

```
    19702   DE  Newark, Lane    Neurys  1   Hernandez   Gus Landscaping Hernandez           
    19380   PA  Chester,    West    Road    Mill    1000    Friedell    Steve   Club    Golf    Mill    Hershey's
    17033   PA  Hershey,    Rd  E.Derry 1000    Club    Country Hershey             
    17033   PA  Hershey Road    Hotel   170 Gardens Hershey
```

**Explanation**

- Split columns breaks the data apart in the way you're already familiar with.
- CountBlanks tells us how many columns are blank; that is, how many columns (+1) we'd have to move to the left before we'd encounter a cell with data; our first cell in the reversed split.
- the 2 in O1 says that from column O the number of rows to move left to the first data is the value defined in column N for this row, plus 2.
- Each time we go 1 column to the right of O we need to go an additional 2 to the left to encounter the next column in our reversed split (P1 is O1+2 because P is 1 to the right of O and the data we're after is 1 to the left of the data we were looking for in O; so 1+1=>2).
- O2 has the complicated bit.

  - Check that we've not gone beyond the first row; if we have just return a blank.
  - Create a relative formula; i.e. rather than defining a named cell (such as "A1") we say how many rows / columns to move.  R[-1] means move 1 row up, C[5] means move 5 columns to the right, R[2]C[-3] means 2 rows down, 3 columns left.  In our case we're only using columns, going back the number of columns determined by N2 + O1 (or as appropriate for whichever cell we're in).
  - False just says we're using this relative functionality rather than the normal absolute cell reference method.
- Copying formulas for all rows/columns just populates the rest of the data (i.e. as opposed to just O2).
- Copying and paste-valueing the data means you can get rid of formulas and just have nice clean data to work with going forwards.

Answer (score 0):

If your data starts in `A2` -

In B2 use - `=LEFT(A2,MIN(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A2&1234567890))-1)` to get customer

in C2 use - `=REPLACE(A2,1,LEN(B2),"")` to get full address